# How to access opencv contour point indexes in python?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, contour

Is there way to access the `contour[i][j]` in python?

I am struggling to translate this c++ into python, because the data structures are different. It's being hard making comparisions

```
static double distanceBtwPoints(const cv::Point a, const cv::Point b)
{
     double xDiff = a.x - b.x;
     double yDiff = a.y - b.y;

     return std::sqrt((xDiff * xDiff) + (yDiff * yDiff));
}

static int findNearestPointIndex(const cv::Point pt, const vector<Point> points)
{
    int nearestpointindex = 0;
    double distance;
    double mindistance = 1e+9;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
    {
        distance = distanceBtwPoints(pt,points[i]);

        if( distance < mindistance )
        {
            mindistance =  distance;
            nearestpointindex = i;
        }
    }
    return nearestpointindex;
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Point pt0;
    int shift=0; // optional value for drawing scaled
    Scalar color = Scalar(0,0,0);

    char* filename = argc >= 2 ? argv[1] : (char*)"test.png";
    Mat img = imread(filename);
    if (img.empty())
        return -1;

    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Point> contour;
    findContours( bw, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE );

    contour = contours[0];
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        if( contour.size() < contours[i].size() )
            contour = contours[i];
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        if( contour != contours[i] && contours[i].size() > 10 )
        {
            for ( size_t j = 0; j <  contours[i].size(); j++)
            {
                pt0 = contours[i][j];
               line(src,pt0,contour[findNearestPointIndex(pt0,contour)],color,1,LINE_8,shift);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for the patient and answers.

Comment: What have you got so far ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ekMB48rV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCV Python `findCountours` can be used like this

```
import cv2
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
# contours = [array([[[x1,  y1]], ..., [[xn,  yn]]]), array([[[x1,  y1]], ..., [[xn,  yn]]])]
contour = contours[0] # contours[i], where i = index of the contour
# contour = [[[x1,  y1]], [[x2,  y2]], ..., [[xn,  yn]]]
# contour[0] = [[x1,  y1]]
# contour[0][0] = [x1,  y1]
# contour[0][0][0] = x1
# contour[0][0][1] = y1
```

That's what you need

```
pt0 = contour[i][j][0] # that's what you need to replace pt0 = contours[i][j];
# pt0 = [x, y], where pt0[0] = x, pt0[1] = y
```

Comment: How can I impose this condition ? :` if( contour != contours[i] && contours[i].size() > 10 )`

Comment: `contours[i]` is a NumPy array. To get its number of rows, just get `contours[i].shape[0]`

Comment: I mean, c++ `contours[i].size()` == python `contours[i].shape[0]`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: And 'if( contour != contours[i] ' ?

As you can see in c++ code, the if condition is a litle tricky. The 1st part is about "verify is the contour is not the largest"  and 2nd part is about the contour lenght/area

Comment: The equivalent of this c++ `if` would be `if not np.array_equal(contour, contours[i]) and contours[i].shape[0] > 10:`

Comment: `   for ( size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)` is equivalent to `for  i in range(len(contours)):` ?

Comment: If my answer was correct for this question, please accept it. I can continue to help you in [this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89819/discussion-between-berriel-and-marco).

Comment: @marco please add your converted part of python code. maybe i will comment on it.

Comment: @Sturkmen I'm having problems translating your code.
1- python behaviour, 2- it looks opencv findcontours returns different things. For instance, on the external contour routine I get only one contour. So, the loops don't work.

Comment: i don't believe it :) if you have time let me try to find solution asking others how some parts of my code can be converted.

Comment: It's being hard. opencv python is tricky :\ There is the discussion: 
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89819/discussion-between-berriel-and-marco
I've tried some solutions, without sucess. I think the main loops are correct, the problem is the condition is not met. The contour of str is only 1, so there is no contour. Problem it is needed another findcontour flag

Comment: @sturkmen the data structures in python are different of the c++. Now I'm in trouble in findnearestpoint function.
And, probably the way that it is called on the loop, with cv.line, should be in another way.

Comment: i am sorry. i think i tried to help you by my best.thank to @berak who gave main key part of python code. try to find solution to other parts. i think my c++ code is clear and can be converted to python.

Comment: @sturkmen you are right. Thank you very much. I open a new question on opencv forum. It makes more sense, and I think everything is clearer.
http://answers.opencv.org/question/71201/help-translate-c-to-python/